# Select Random Images, check if in specific range and display accordingly

Tags: javascript, html

I need to draw 5 cards, and check whether these are of the same type (*Heart*, *Spade* etc.)

I given them names from `1-52` (where `1-13` are *hearts*, etc.)

Now I need to create a JavaScript function that selects 5 cards from these 52 checks if these are of same type (*eg. spade*)

If it's true, than show those cards in a table, otherwise, repeat loop till successful and I need to show how many times the loop repeated.

I tried some approaches, but since I don't know much about JavaScript, I'm stuck. Could someone please help me with this?

Here is what I've tried :

```
function flush() {
    for (var picked_card = 0; picked_card < 6; picked_card++) {

        var picked_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
        document.write(
            '<table>'
            '<tr>'
            '<td>'
            '<img src="' + picked_card + '" '.jpg />'
            '</td>'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: no one have answer of my question :/

Comment: if you want to draw cards from the same type why not pick 5 random numbers in the range of the card type e.g. for hearts a random number between 1 and 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var hand = [];
var loopCount = 0;
while (hand.length < 5) {
    var picked_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
    var handEmpty = hand.length == 0;
    if (handEmpty) {
        hand.push(picked_card);
    } 
    else {
        var cardInHand = hand.indexOf(picked_card) != -1;
        var handColor = Math.floor((hand[0] - 1) / 13);
        var cardColor = Math.floor((picked_card - 1) / 13);
        if (!cardInHand && cardColor == handColor) {
            hand.push(picked_card);
        }
        else {
            loopCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

And to display:

```
document.write('<table><tbody><tr>');
for(i in hand) {
    document.write('<td><img src="' + hand[i] + '.jpg" /></td>');
}
document.write('</tr></tbody></table>');
```

Comment: can you please tell me the code to output these 5 cards in a table having single row & 5 columns?

Answer (score 0):

To find the card-type make an integer-division by 13 of the 'card name', using names of 0..51. for 0..12 you'll get 0: Heart, for 13..25 1: Spade, etc. Than draw while picking cards of the same type; re-try on the first card of another type. When you got 5 cards together, you're done.

```
function drawFlush() {

 for(var count = 0;; count++) {

  var type = -1;
  var picked_cards = [];

  while(picked_cards.length < 5) {

    var card;
    do {
      card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
    } while( -1 != picked_cards.indexOf(card));

    var card_type = Math.floor( card / 13);
    if( -1 == type) {
     type = card_type;
    } else {
     if(card_type != type) {
       break;
      }
    }
    picked_cards.push(card);
  }
 }
 return {
  number_of_tries : count,
  picked_cards : picked_cards
 }
}
```

@Samy: right, not pick a card twice ;-)

Note: Here it is counted how many times a complete hand of 5 cards must be drawn until the first 'flush' appears. In theory, this should average on 1 * (12/51) * (11/50) * (10/49) * (9/48), for each draw as the number of 'positive' possible choices out of the number of remaining cards, if you're interested in this.

Comment: can you please tell me the code to output these 5 cards in a table having single row & 5 colums?